# ST_pointN function to retrieve point from geometry column in table

Tags: postgresql

I'm having trouble with the following query in PostgreSQL.

```
select * 
from st_astext(st_pointn(texas_roads_gcs.geom from texas_roads_gcs,1))
```

Here I'm trying to get point from geometry column(geom) in the table named "texas_roads_gcs" but it doesn't run properly. It gives the folloving error.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from"
LINE 1: ...t * from st_astext(st_pointn(texas_roads_gcs.geom from texas...
                                                             ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "from"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 56
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use these functions just like any scalar functions - with column name as parameter

```
 select *, st_astext(st_pointn(geom,1))
 from texas_roads_gcs
```

or a single value returned by a correct subquery:

```
 select st_astext(st_pointn(
     (select geom from texas_roads_gcs limit 1)
 ,1))
```